# Copy entire content from one Word document to another using C#

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word

I am trying to copy entire content (including page numbers, and page layout) from a word document to another, using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`.
I cannot use SaveAs method because the document in which I want to paste the contents is already created and it contains VBA code.
Also, I cannot use XML related code because the document in which I am copying the content is in the older format. This document is part of an old way of uploading a document to a server database, using VBA code.

Using VBA code, I can copy the entire content without any issue.

```
 Selection.WholeStory
 Selection.Copy
 Windows("document.doc").Activate
 Selection.WholeStory
 Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
```

For C#, I used `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` to replicate the VBA code.

```
Word.Application objWordOpen = new Word.Application();
objWordOpen.Visible = false;
Word.Document doclocal = objWordOpen.Documents.Open(filepath);

doclocal.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
doclocal.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();

Document d1 = objWordOpen.Documents.Open(filepath2);
d1.Activate();
d1.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
d1.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat(Word.WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting);
```

I have also tried using range

```
Word.Range oRange = doclocal.Content;
oRange.Copy();
```

The content is copied into the document, but without headers and footers. Also, when using `Selection.WholeStory()` approach, the page margins settings don't get copied. 
What changes should I make to the c# code in order to achieve my result?

Comment: Try opening both files first and then copying.

Comment: Can you just copy the whole actual file instead?

Comment: @GSerg, it works opening both files before, but I don't understand what's the relevance. You could post an answer, explaining why, if you came across this issue. Thank you!

Comment: The act of opening a document messes up with `Selection`. It's an observation, I do not have concrete documentation.

Comment: @GSerg, I can see why it would mess up with the `Selection`. However, my initial code opened the document after copying the selection, so the initial selection shouldn't matter anymore. Anyhow, please post your comment an anwser so I can mark the Question as anwered. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Office applications have complicated relationships with the clipboard. Between various optimisations that may lead to [cryptic prompts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/287392/how-to-programmatically-turn-off-the-clipboard-warning-message), and numerous formats they support, it is best to not do anything remotely funny between a `Copy` and a `Paste`.

The VBA code follows this advice, the C# code opens a document between copying and pasting.

Make sure you open the documents in advance and not in the middle of a copypaste.